# OptionError: optparse.py invalid action: error

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

Greetings I am receiving an error when I attempt to place arguments into my python script. Here is the function

```
from optparse import OptionParser

def getparams():
usage = "usage: %prog -d <dcb_ip> -p <port> "
parser = OptionParser(usage)
parser.add_option("-d", "--dcb_ip",
                  action="store",
                  dest="dcb_ip",
                  default="172.14.20.31",
                  help="Specifiy the IP address of the device, default is [%default].")
parser.add_option("-p", "--port",
                  action="store",
                  type="int",
                  dest="port",
                  default=51500,
                  help="Specify the pcl port of the monitor, default is [%default].")
parser.add_option("-i", "--interactive", action="store_true",  default=False, dest="interactive")
parser.add_option("-l", "--loop", action="store",  default=False, dest="loop")
parser.add_option("-w", "--write", action="write_mem",  default=False, dest="interactive")  #Write HART option
parser.add_option("-r", "--read", action="read_mem",  default=False, dest="interactive")
parser.add_option("-c", "--Cancel", action="cancel_mem",  default=False, dest="interactive")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)    
return options
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\devices_15_JUL_2013\RSimulator.py", line 73, in getparams
    parser.add_option("-w", "--write", action="write_mem",  default=False)  #Write mem option
OptionError: option -w/--write: invalid action: 'write_mem''
```

I thought -c might be a common option or something but even when I changed it still did not work :(

Comment: What do you expect the `-w`, `-r` and `-c` options to *do* when specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write_mem`, `read_mem` and `cancel_mem` are not valid values for the `action` keyword; see [Standard option actions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-actions) for what *is* available.

It is not clear what you expect those options to *do*, however. You specified the destination as `interactive`, but that is *already* in use as a boolean flag for the `-i`, `--interactive` option.

If you wanted to set boolean flags for each of these in their `_mem` options, then do so with `store_true` actions:

```
parser.add_option("-w", "--write", action="store_true", default=False, dest="write_mem")
parser.add_option("-r", "--read", action="store_true", default=False, dest="read_mem")
parser.add_option("-c", "--cancel", action="store_true", default=False, dest="cancel_mem")
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out :)